Is this question from Unix&Linux (closed there) suitable for SuperUser community?
Is this question about a tool for measuring efficiency of filesystems and experienced efficiency/overhead values for types of filesystems (respectively, more in general asking about a tool on Linux, suitable for measuring data throughput on filesystem directories) suitable for SuperUser community and content?
(I'd prefer the simple 1st revision version for asking.)
(thx)

Your first revision does not seem on topic. It asks "why are there no tools" and "if there is a tool, explain how it works" The first one there is more about why people have not done something and the second one is basically asking for us to recommend products and explain what they do which is off topic for two reasons. 1. We do not do product recommendations, and 2. Explaining in depth how software achieves something could be anything from 1 line to an entire book, it's far too broad. Your problem should be reasonably scoped.

Honestly I think the same comments as posted on your question apply here, the question is vague and unfocused and "could a tool do something" is very much asking for guesses. Sure, many tools can do many things, but you've not asked about any particular tool, so the only answer is "probably a tool could do that" with little else. You have no real solid answerable question IMO.

@Mokubai in general i do agree, but with the task of 'monitoring throughput for filesystem directory's data IO', that is a very specific and rare case for a tool on Linux, AFAI_know, there's is no basic tool in all known to me distributions and if there's an answer at all, there are very limited options available. i'ld rewrite the question for being at suitable wording, maybe that would need advice or review. Thanks for Your input.

@beyondtime - You can [edit] your question at any time. Until you improve the quality of your question I cannot recommend you submit your question at Super User.  You can [edit] your question then request it be migrated to Super User.  However, as currently written, the question migration likely would be rejected. You should ask on Meta Unix and Linux on ways to improve your question to meet their community guidelines.

No it isn't.
Questions should be specific, clear, and demonstrate a certain minimum amount of self effort. Questions should also not ask directly/only for product recommendations.
Your question fails on these points.
There is a Software Recommendation sister site where part of your question may be on topic.
A few general recommendations that might help you write a more succinct question:

The first sentence begins with "To my knowledge...". I like that turn of phrase myself, but you're posting a question, so a phrasing that emphasizes not your own knowledge, but your need to learn and expand your knowledge will fit better: "I am not aware of..." or "I don't know of any...".
The second sentence in your post, beginning "By the way..." you fully admit to be immaterial to the question: so don't include it. Delete it and do not include it. Remember the turtle in Finding Nemo: Focus dude!
Both the first sentences are only tangentially related to the next part of the post. Just delete them and start with "What is the range...". THAT is actually a pretty clear question that might even be on topic on the site it's already on. You started badly: so remove the bad start.
Consider rephrasing that actual question. It's a VERY run-on sentence that seems to contain a few clauses that could be broken out into their own sentences. Maybe start with a simple question "What is the percentage difference between the listed file size and the real size of the file and all associated metadata for these filesystem types...?", then ask the same question again with the greater detail: "Specifically, including this, that, and the other metadata types, and moving a hypothetical file specifically X MB between these two folders on the same partition..."
You then jump back to talking about a product, but there's no indication HOW this product relates to the preceding sentences and information, so it feels like you've jumped back to another topic. It feels like you have 2 or 3 semi-related topics all cut up, shaken about, and then thrown down into the post.
When you say you checked ALL of the questions about the topic, we don't believe you: it's a throw-away claim and so we ignore it because that is the polite thing to do. Instead, tell us the specific things you've considered. It might be alright to include links, but even that isn't really necessary if you list the specific things you've tried and why they didn't answer your question/meet your needs/solve your problem.

These are just my observations of why your question in its current form is not a good fit here and was closed there. I recommend that you focus on a specific question, REALLY FOCUS, cut the off topic bits, and then petition that the question be reopened where it is. That behavior is respected and encouraged on all the sites in this system: Closing question isn't often a "go away", it is instead a "you need to fix this, then we'll revisit it". So, edit your question there.
